# How to call a class rather than a method inside a class?

Tags: c#

so I want to make it easy to call `Console.WriteLine()`  (from the namespace system) so I wrote:

```
using System;

namespace main
{
    namespace easier
    {
        public class print
        {
            public print(string input)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to call `print("Hello World);` it says `CS1955: Non-invocable member 'print' cannot be used like a method`.

Is there a way so I don't have to do `class.print("Hello World");` just `print("Hello World");`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could make an extension method for strings and then call `"somestring".print();`

Comment: See `using static` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `using static`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

```cs
using System;
using static Easier;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Print("message");
    }
}

public static class Easier
{
    public static void Print(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```